# WeChat: "Voice call may be compromised and incur charges on current network"

Tags: iphone, applications

In a WeChat video call, I periodically see the following message: "Voice call may be compromised and incur charges on current network.", even after I press OK. What does this mean? How can I stop this message from re-appearing?

Answer (score 1):

Best guess - it means you are not on wifi, so are [potentially] paying regular data charge over your standard carrier network.

If you have a huge data allowance you can probably ignore this, but 2GB a month or pay-as-you-go & you'll be eating that allowance rapidly on a video call.